# Matlab Display variable output in dialog box

Tags: matlab, variables, dialog, output, box

I would like to display in the message dialog box the output of a variable.

```
msgbox('Your answer is   ');
```

The variable's name is var and it equals 2. How may I edit the code so that I display the value of that variable there (where the blank space is)?

Input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
message = sprintf('Your answer is %d', var)
msgbox(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is going to work too

```
     msgbox(['Your answer is=   ',num2str(var)]);
```